# TIBCO MFT Server Installation

Tags: file-transfer, tibco

I've asked by manager to check and confirm where the TIBCO MFT is installed on IBM AIX server. I'm completely new to TIBCO and don't know what is the installation directory of this software.

Could somebody please help me to find where it is installed on AIX server.

Answer (score 2):

If your server is configured properly, then you should have an environment variable called `CFROOT` set that points to the installation directory (execute a `echo $CFROOT` to see its value).

The installation directory can be set during the installation process to some arbitrary directory, so in theory it could be anywhere.  The default however should be `/mftps`, other likely options include `/opt/mftps`, or `/opt/tibco/mftps`.

Answer (score 1):

Althaf ,

You can use "find" command as well to search for mftps on Server to know the directory.